# Add visual editor style only on widgets.php page

Tags: widgets, visual-editor

I'm attempting to add a visual editor style with the function `add_editor_style('visual-editor.css');`, but only on the widgets admin' page, and not on post editor screens. I'm using a [visual editor widget by Black Studio](https://wordpress.org/plugins/black-studio-tinymce-widget/).

I've not been able to separate the two; the custom styling appears on both the visual editor widget and the post editor screen. Why would this be?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'on_widget_page' );
function on_widget_page(){
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( $screen->id = 'widgets' ) {
        add_editor_style('visual-editor.css');
    }
}
```

Thanks very much for your time.

Comment: you have a php error, you use "=" instead of "=="

Comment: Using `$screen->id == 'widgets'` seems to disable the visual editor style altogether, for me.

Comment: maybe it does, but you are not going to get anywhere with broken php..... have you check what is the screen id on those pages?